# Schema.org Event does not appear in Google Search and Bing

Tags: seo, schema.org, rich-snippets

I always wondered how freelancers and businesses add their events to Google and Bing to make them searchable like this:

[image]

Finally I found some forum explaining that Google read them from JSON-LD format which you should embed into a web page on your web site.

I followed instructions and made one for my site in the beginning of the week for the upcoming weekend. However 5 days since it still not shown up if you type "events in walnut creek ca this weekend".

Here is [my `Event` in the Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=oksana.photography%2Fhalloween-mini-session).

I've also added JSON-LD for the business itself on a home page.

Any ideas what did I do wrong?

Comment: Note that you don’t *have* to use JSON-LD, you could also use Microdata or RDFa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structured data itself looks valid to me.

First, confirm that Google has successfully indexed your structured data. You can do so by viewing the [Structured Data Report in Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2650907?hl=en).

If Google hasn't indexed your structured data, you can explicitly submit the page to Google Search Console for indexing, which usually speeds up your updated page's inclusion in Google Search (as well as Google's indexation of your structured data).

If Google *has* indexed your structured data but your event is still not showing up in Google Search Results, that means that one of the following is true:

1. Google believes your website is not trustworthy enough to show event data from
2. Google does not believe your event is important enough to show
3. Your website itself does not rank highly enough for the keywords you are typing in

For tips to increase your website's ranking and trustworthiness in the eyes of Google, you can always check out this Webmasters SE thread:

[What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)